# how to find the perimeter in similar figures

Tags: geometry

how would you find the perimeter?  I've tried to search it up but the websites say to do different things and I don't know how to do it.can anyone help?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiV2y.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If two figures are similar by a factor $k$ then:

$1)$ $S_1=k^2S_2$

$2)$ $P_1=kP_2$

where $S_i$ is the area and $P_i$ is the perimeter. That give us:

$$\frac{S_1}{S_2}=\left(\frac{P_1}{P_2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Did you understand?